# Pricelist parser

Tags: c#, data-mining

I have to create Pricelist parser that imports data from excel or csv and put it in database. I have no problems to get data from source. I need to find columns that contains price, product title and description automaticaly.

What can you suggest how to do that, is there common methods or libraries?

Data sample 1:

```
Intel Core 2 Duo E6300 (2.80GHz, 1066MHz, 2MB, S775) tray  |    83
Intel Core 2 Duo E6500 (2.93GHz, 1066MHz, 2MB, S775) tray  |    86
```

Data sample 2:

```
     Title                     Description                Guaranty     Price  
Intel Core 2 Duo E6300  |  2.80GHz, 1066MHz, 2MB, S775   |  12       |  83    
Intel Core 2 Duo E6500  |  2.93GHz, 1066MHz, 2MB, S775   |  6        |  86
```

Data sample 3:

```
 UPC                Title                      Price
 456546545     |  Intel Core 2 Duo E6300    |  83 
 4654654654    |  Intel Core 2 Duo E6500    |  out of stock
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of the data? I'm guessing there are no header rows.

Comment: Yes, no headers. Something like this:

Comment: How should the data be parsed in your sample data above? Is the 83 a price?

Comment: Yes 83 is price. This sample is easy to parse. I can try parse column value if it contains text, then it is product title if number then price, but real data is not so definite. There may be columns that contains product id and product description.

Comment: Isn't this something you should do manually, just to be safe - e.g. pop up a few records in a GUI and get the user to pick which is which before you process the whole fule? Or does this need to be done non-interactively?

Comment: Yes, this need to be done non-interactively. Suppose we have folder with lots of pricelists in various formats.

Comment: Sounds like you need to standardize the price lists so you always know what data is in what column.  Or you need to place headers at the top and use that to parse the information.  Just my two-cents.

Comment: @Nathan Loding, 
this is not my pricelists I will take them from various sources

Comment: @Orsol: If you don't know what the format of your input will be, and you can't have user interaction to help specify, you can't possibly know how to parse the data.  Is it possible to specify some configuration for each file?  Perhaps for each `mydata.txt` file you could also require a `mydata.txt.config` file that could include format information for that file?  Of course, you'd still need interaction at *some* point in order to populate that file, but at least the actual parse could run unattended...

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote an address parser and the general strategy I used was to first pull out all the items that have a distinguishable pattern. In my case I first found the Postal Code which is analogous to price in your example. From there I found the state code, etc.

In your example I would find the Price and remove it from the line. From there you will need to find some pattern in the data that would allow you to parse our the product code. Without seeing more REAL data it is hard to decide what that is. In my address parser I used address suffixes (Rd, St, Court, etc) to help identify the end of an address line.

If you can provide more data we could probably be more helpful.

Comment: That's closer. I've added more data samples.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server, I would suggest not creating a program at all and using SQL Server Integration Services, which has built-in support for CSV and Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the quality of your input (are all input strings equally formatted), you could try the following:

```
string s = "Intel Core 2 Duo E6300 (2.80GHz, 1066MHz, 2MB, S775) tray  |    83";
string firstPart = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf("(")).Trim(); //returns "Intel Core 2 Duo E6300"
string secondPart = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("(") + 1, s.IndexOf(")") - s.IndexOf("(") - 1).Trim(); //returns "2.80GHz, 1066MHz, 2MB, S775"
string thirdPart = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(")") + 1, s.IndexOf("|") - s.IndexOf(")") - 1).Trim(); //returns "tray"
string fourthPart = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("|") + 1, s.Length - s.IndexOf("|") - 1).Trim(); //returns "83"
```

But when your data is not uniformely formatted, you might need to do some (or a lot) of checking before you can use the above functions.

Comment: I think the problem was guessing which column contains which type of data.